# coverity STDIN dereference errors

Tags: c, stdin, coverity

In my C application I attempt to take in a single char from a user (no need to sanitize it) for commands. Functions such as getchar(), fgetc(stdin), and scanf(...) all give me the following error when used with coverity:  `Event dereference: Dereferencing "_stdin()", which is known to be "NULL"`. I use aggressiveness-level set to medium for the coverity-analyze command.

For example, I have tried checking cAck against NULL, stdin against NULL, ferror(stdin), against EOF, and feof(stdin) before using the cAck variable (Edit: I had tried without any of these checks and coverity still complained). How would I make something like the following run without coverity complaints?

```
char cAck;
if( (cAck = fgetc(stdin)) != NULL)
{
// do something with cAck
}
```

Comment: You need to read more about [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc). What does it really return, both type and values? And remember that `NULL` is a null *pointer*, C doesn't have the concept of null values.

Comment: In your answer, you say that Coverity complains even if you do not test `stdin==NULL`.  That is unclear from the question as currently written.  It would be helpful to edit your question to be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including specifying what compiler you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since (evidently, for your compiler) fgetc is a macro that dereferences stdin

As Scott noted, this was basically the issue I was running into. I only tried checking `stdin==NULL` and returning after in hopes that it would see that stdin is not NULL for the rest of the code, but coverity complained with and without that check. As an aside, I believe coverity would additionally flag that as a FORWARD_NULL error if I checked that stdin was NULL and continued to use it.

Checking against EOF did not solve it. Fortunately, using the scanf("%c", &cAck) function removed the coverity stdin dereference error which is the main issue. I check the return value and the bounds of the char input as well, the latter being for the coverity tainted variable issue.

Comment: You *still* need to check for errors from `scanf()` - what happens if the stream is closed and no characters were ever written to it?

Comment: How about `getchar()` instead of `scanf("%c")`?

Comment: Coverity complains (as noted in my original question) for getchar(). scanf works well for this.

Comment: And yet, `scanf` without checking the return value is the most dangerous thing to write.

Comment: My mistake, I clarified that I did indeed check the return value and bounds. The scanf was more to point out that coverity does not give it a stdin dereference error which is the main issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

The message:

> Event dereference: Dereferencing "_stdin()", which is known to be "NULL"

means that, somewhere in your code, you tested `stdin` against `NULL`, for example:

```
  if (stdin == NULL) {
    printf("stdin was NULL!\n");
    // but I kept going anyway, rather than aborting
  }
```

Indeed, you stated:

> I have tried checking [...] stdin against NULL

Coverity sees this test, assumes the programmer is checking for a condition that might be true, and therefore concludes that it is possible that `stdin` is, in fact, `NULL`.  Since (evidently, for your compiler) `fgetc` is a macro that dereferences `stdin`, Coverity then concludes that dereference could fail, leading to undefined behavior (typically a crash).

Although `stdin` has type `FILE*`, which is a pointer type, it is never `NULL` on startup, and attempting to set it to `NULL` is, itself, undefined behavior (see [cppreference: stdin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/std_streams)), so it is generally safe to assume that `stdin` is never `NULL`.  Therefore, you should not confuse tools or other programmers by checking whether it is `NULL`.

That is, **remove the check** for `stdin==NULL`, and then Coverity should stop complaining.

---

Separately, as noted in comments, the return value of [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) is `int`, so it is nonsensical to compare its return value to [`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL), which is a pointer (to a first approximation at least).  Instead, you probably want to compare it to the constant [`EOF`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io):

```
char cAck;
if( (cAck = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
                          // ^^^ changed
{
// do something with cAck
}
```

Comment: If you tried running this on coverity it would give an stdin dereference error...

Comment: @Jegor Calling `fgetc` like this is very commonplace.  It would be highly unlikely for a tool to report it since there would be huge numbers of false positives in almost every C program.  I think there must be something unusual about your setup that is confusing the tool.  But you haven't given a complete input program, nor specified what compiler (with version) you are using, or operating system, or Coverity version.  That's why I asked for an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).